# Importing products - process lasts forever

Tags: magento-1.7, import, csv, products

I have two Magento 1.7.0.2 installations: one is on a shared hosting installed using cPanel and the other is a local install I've done on my Ubuntu Server 12.04 machine.

Since the one on the shared hosting is just for learning and demo purposes, and I have now setup the local one, I need to import the list of products into the local install.
For this I have a csv file comprising of 2685 products.

When I begin the import procedure and select the csv file and "check data", validation results show:

```
Checked rows: 2685, checked entities: 2685, invalid rows: 0, total errors: 0

File is valid! To start import process press "Import" button
```

The problem I'm facing is, that when I click import button, only about 1600 or 1700 items are imported and the import procedure seems to run forever till I stop it.

The same csv file imports perfectly into the shared hosting version.

Would really appreciate some help on this, pls.

Comment: Most probably it's a memory related issue, or a time limit issue.

Comment: Have you tried splitting your list into three parts? EDIT: Sorry, I missed that is works on your shared server. I agree with Marius

Comment: Thanks Marius. The file size of the csv is 882k. Do I need to set some time limits? I tried searching but didn't see anything in System >> Configuration.

Comment: Have you created a phpinfo file to compare the two?

Comment: Thanks Brentwtererson. How would I make a phpinfo file? and which "two" do I need to compare?

Comment: you can make a php page with phpinfo(); you don't have to do echo. Make one for each site and compare the two. Also look at your httpd.conf to make sure your timeout is set quite high (18000)

Comment: Well, as for phpinfo, the shared webhost uses PHP Version 5.2.17; while the local Ubuntu server uses PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8.
The httpd.conf file in the local ubuntu server is blank

Comment: Try splitting the import file in smaller files.